# Cypress - API Call with request payload - how to handle payload in the code

Tags: cypress

I need help to understand how to use cy.route() and cy.wait() to check if each of the three API calls below result is 200 or say successful.

HTTP address

Request URL: https://......../ABC
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK

Request Payload - Based on the value, I am seeing three API calls using above Http request as below

```
{CountryCode: "USA", countryRatingType: "A"}
{CountryCode: "USA", countryRatingType: "B"}
{CountryCode: "USA", countryRatingType: "C"}
```

In the above three API calls, countryRatingType remains static for respective API but country code value changes as per input

Let's say if I selected CAN as a country it will be

```
{CountryCode: "CAN", countryRatingType: "A"}
{CountryCode: "CAN", countryRatingType: "B"}
{CountryCode: "CAN", countryRatingType: "C"}
```

Comment: 3 API calls using same url and different request ?

Comment: That's Correct.

Comment: I was playing around today and was able to find the solution.I used "expect(xhr.requestBody).includes({ countryCode: CAN, countryRatingType: "A" })" and it worked. later on i replaced CAN with fixture to make it dynamic

Answer (score 1):

```
cy.server()
cy.route({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'https://......../ABC',
    }).as('abc')
cy.visit('https://......../ABC') 
cy.wait('@abc').then((xhr) => {
      assert.isNotNull(xhr.response.body.data, 'call to server has data')
    })   
cy.get('@abc').should('have.property', 'status', 200)
```

Comment: Hi @user2214507, welcome to stackoverflow! You're answering a question which is over 4 months old. Please try to answer new questions, this is more helpful. And don't just add a code block. Explain your answer, so the creator is able to learn from you.

Comment: I believe it's totally fine answer old questions (there is also a badge for this). 
I found this post today (2 years later) because I have the same problem.